Raydium CLMM Config ID
I'm creating CLMM Pool using Raydim SDK. can anyone tell what is clmmConfigID and how can I create or get it?
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/blob/3aa9b99598f7a6881b4d67e2c3d0c3a2d2310410/src/clmmCreatePool.ts#L70
